# prevent ng-show effect on child

Tags: html, angularjs

Is it possible to prevent the effect of `ng-show` on a specific child element.

Lets say I have the following html.

```
<div ng-show="showParent" class="parent">
   <div class="childOne"></div>        <!-- don't hide this -->
   <div class="childTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Now what I would like to achieve is hiding everything except `childOne`. Actually hiding a parent, but one or some of its children?

Comment: You'll probably need to simply move `ng-show` to the child elements. If that's generated dynamically, show us more markup.

Comment: Can i clarify that what you want to have is always hide ChildOne ?

Comment: no, its simplified. its about preventing the effect of ng-hide on an arbitrary element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  The HTML standard prevents that.  All children get hidden when the parent gets hidden, and AngularJS just adds things to HTML, it doesn't change it.

However, AngularJS allows one variable to control multiple elements, and can probably help us get the same affects you want.  So let's go back to what you are really trying to accomplish.  To do this, we're going to need some more details that you took out in this question to make the question smaller (and thank you for that).  What about just hiding childTwo is not working for you?  Are there other things in parent you need to hide?  We can put those in seperate elements (div or span or something) and hide those with the same variable as we hide ChildTwo.  Does parent have some formatting (say, a border or something) you need to hide?  We can change what classes are on parent based on the same variable we use to hide the other elements to something that removes the border and any other styling, effectively making it not visible, although still technically present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`ngShow` relies on a CSS class (`.ng-hide`). You may be able to override that class with your own more specific selector for just the divs you want excluded from the directive.

```
<div class="parent" ng-show="showParent">
  <div class="childOne nghide-override"></div>
  <div class="childTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

*(I'm unable to test this right now, but I'll mock something up shortly and edit/remove this if it doesn't work.)*

You could also just split the children out into divs and hide the second div:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="shown children">
    <div class="childOne"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden children" ng-show="showParent">
    <div class="childTwo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the first option with `visibility: visible!important`. Is that what you mean? But it doesnt work. Your second option is not really an option in my situation..

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery unwrap. 
Include jquery in your application:

```
bower install jquery --save
```

Set on ready unwrap to specified div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".childOne").unwrap();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This would be a bit overkill for something like this to have to include another library for a simple functionality.

Comment: Do you know other working solution? Display: none removes element from dom, so no other solutions, except changing ng-hide, removing display: none and adding visibility: hidden. Changing angular css wouldn't be also overkill?

Comment: My main concern with this solution would be that it forces you to using jquery by using this library which can increase the size of your application significantly.  Personally the best solution in my opinion would  be two separate elements or simply switching a class.